# htaccess conflict causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have trawled - and tried - many different ways listed on stackoverflow to try to redirect http:// to https://, but I keep getting a redirect loop.

e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I think it is because of something lower down in the htaccess file - which works fine until I add any of these https redirect at the top (below the RewriteEngine On).
This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+home\.php\?su=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /home.php?su=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(prog|weblinks|photos|cal|officials|contactus|search)\.php\?su=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(prog|weblinks|photos|cal|officials|contactus|search).html$ /$2.php?su=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/content\.php\?su=([^\s&]+)&PgID=(\d+)&pu=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /content.php?su=$1&PgID=$2&pu=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/completed\.php\?su=([^\s&]+)&RoYear=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /completed.php?su=$1&RoYear=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/thumbs\.php\?su=([^\s&]+)&PgID=(\d+)&pu=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/thumbs/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/thumbs/(\d+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /thumbs.php?su=$1&PgID=$2&pu=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Very grateful for any pointers - this is a charity site I run.

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Thanks @anubhava the redirect address appears in the address bar, but the developer box just shows [link] 'the page at https://etc failed to load and the contents of the pages says err too many redirects

Comment: What are the URLs you see repeatedly in `Networking` tab of `Chrome dev tool `?

Comment: I see the correct redirected url, but with a status of 302

Comment: What URL it is before redirect and what it becomes after redirect?

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't seem to matter; it might be     [link] http:// or www. or both and it redirects with whatever was there before, but with https. I will leave it in place so you can see - www.rotary-site.org/websites-for-trf

Comment: ok try replacing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` with `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443` and retest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104717/discussion-between-chris-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

We tried numerous variants, but the one that worked in the end was
    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Thanks to @anubhava for your efforts